# Create Comparator using map of getter method references

Tags: java, comparator

I have tried to create a Comparator based on object fields that have non-null values using `Comparator.compare` and then chain it with `Comparator.thenCompare`. I have a HashMap that stores a field as a key and getter method reference as a value.

Here is my enum of fields :

```
 public enum BikeProperty {
     BRAND,
     MAX_SPEED,
     WEIGHT,
     SIZE_OF_WHEEL,
     NUMBER_OF_GEARS,
     IS_LIGHT_AVAILABLE,
     BATTERY_CAPACITY,
     COLOR,
     PRICE
}
```

Each of this fields related to some field in `Bike` object.

Next stop is my HashMap that looks like this:

```
    Map<BikeProperty, Function<Bike, Comparable<?>>> fieldToFieldExtractor = new HashMap<>();
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.MAX_SPEED, Bike::getMaxSpeed);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.WEIGHT, Bike::getWeight);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.SIZE_OF_WHEEL, Bike::getSizeOfWheels);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.NUMBER_OF_GEARS, Bike::getNumberOfGears);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.IS_LIGHT_AVAILABLE, Bike::isLightsAvailable);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.BATTERY_CAPACITY, Bike::getBatteryCapacity);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.COLOR, Bike::getColor);
    fieldToFieldExtractor.put(BikeProperty.PRICE, Bike::getPrice);
```

And finally my method:

```
public Comparator<Bike> provideComparatorByFields(Set<BikeProperty> fields) {
    Comparator<Bike> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Bike::getBrand);
    fields
            .forEach(s -> comparator.thenComparing(fieldToFieldExtractor.get(s)));
    return comparator;
}
```

My idea is to pass to method already filtered `Set<BikePropery>`, iterate through this and chain comparator methods.

For example, for given set `Set.of(BikeProperty.PRICE,BikeProperty.IS_LIGHT_AVAILABLE)`, generate following comparator : `Comparator.compare(Bike::getBrand).thenCompare(Bike::getPrice).thenCompare(Bike::isLightAvailable)`

**Problem :**
Created comparator have only one default comparing of `Bike::getBrand()`. Therefore, I had a question, is it possible to do so at all, and if possible, bring some advice. Thank you!

**Update**

When I`m creating comparator (for example) from my main method, it looks like  this : [image]

[image]

But when I`m creating it in my method by forEach loop it looks like this:

[image]

**So it does not append any thenComparing() keyExtractor to comparator**

Comment: Hi Nick, so you want to compare several bikes. But only compare fields that are non-null ... on ONE of the bikes? Or on both? What if the non-null-fields are mutually exclusive? Would a bike with no maxSpeed be "before" a bike that has a maxSpee?

Comment: So my global task is to find Bike by binary search in array of bikes, but the problem is that searched bike might have a null values in it's fields. I decided to generate comparator by specific non-nullable properties to avoid comparing null fields and other related problems. I've discovered about chaining Comparator comparing calls by getter methods references (keyExtractors) and trying dynamically generate comparator by set of Enum properties

Comment: Maybe, I will try to simplify. I want to create Comparator(like a Builder pattern) based on Java8 thenCompare() method that accept as a parameter getter method reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the changes. `thenCompare` doesn't modify the original comparator, but returns a new one.

```
for (var s : fields) {
    comparator = comparator.thenComparing(fieldToFieldExtractor.get(s)));
}
```